# Unicorn + Rails 7.1: TypeError: wrong argument type strio (expected strio) (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, unicorn

User
I am running a large Rails app with the Unicorn webserver in production. After upgrading from rails 7.0 to 7.1 I am getting the following issues:

Here is the error that happens for every request when running via Unicorn:

```
  127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2023:09:53:30 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 51908 0.0197
TypeError: wrong argument type strio (expected strio) (TypeError)
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:390:in `external_encoding'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:390:in `check_input'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:332:in `check_environment'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:57:in `response'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:35:in `call'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/show_exceptions.rb:27:in `call'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:43:in `call'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/chunked.rb:102:in `call'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/content_length.rb:20:in `call'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:634:in `process_client'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:739:in `worker_loop'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:547:in `spawn_missing_workers'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:143:in `start'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicorn-6.1.0/bin/unicorn:128:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/bin/unicorn:25:in `load'
    /Users/me/installs/ruby/3.2.2/bin/unicorn:25:in `<main>'
```

It happens on all requests. I have of course tried updating Unicorn to the latest master from https://yhbt.net/unicorn.git and rack to the latest version.
As far as I can tell, there are zero matching search results on Google for "wrong argument type strio".
I also can’t find any relevant detail in the unicorn mailing list: https://yhbt.net/unicorn-public/
Neither have I been able to find anything relevant on https://github.com/rack/rack/issues

It seems to fail when calling external_encoding method here https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/f6c583adb0e863e524bacedaf594602964e01078/lib/rack/lint.rb#L393C59-L393C76
that method is implemented in C ... so no clue why that fails due to wrong argument type

What might be causing this and how do I further debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem (although with the puma server). It looked like:

```
[timestamp] Listen loop: #<TypeError: wrong argument type strio (expected strio)>
```

*(Sidenote: take a moment to appreciate the pure silliness of that message)*

The problem, which arose after a routine bundle update which only updated a bunch of minor versions of things, affected only "bare metal" mac development -- docker and linux were fine.

The cause was that the `debug` gem (which we have in our development/test group of course) has a dependency of `irb`.
`irb` at some point between 1.7.x and 1.10.x added a dependency on `rdoc`. `rdoc` depends on `psych` and `psych` depends on `strio`. We resolved it for the time being by adding a direct dependency (in the dev/test group) on `irb` and pinning it to `~> 1.7` to prevent it from going above. This removed `rdoc`, `psych`, and `strio` from our dependency tree.

Note: We didn't bother checking to see if this was an irb 1.8, 1.9 or 1.10 change so it's very possible we could use 1.8 or 1.9 safely, I just didn't particularly care.

so this:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', '~> 1.8'
end
```

became:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', '~> 1.8'
  gem 'irb', '~> 1.7'
end
```

Hope this was your problem also, as this was the only place on the Internet I even found anyone discussing this type of error.